# @staticmethod gives SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python

I have been using a python script for a long while and all of sudden it gives me:

```
  File "youtube-dl.py", line 103
    @staticmethod
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If you want to see the script, its right here: http://bitbucket.org/rg3/youtube-dl/raw/2009.06.29/youtube-dl

What could be the reason?

### Update

I am using python version Python 2.3.4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be using an old Python version that didn't support [decorators](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) yet.

Comment: I am using Python 2.3.4 - is that old?

Comment: Yeah download 2.5!
Changed in version 2.4: Function decorator syntax added.

Comment: Python 2.3 was released in 2003, so yeah, it's old.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.4.html#pep-318-decorators-for-functions-and-methods

Comment: THANK YOU! I have managed to fix it - with a new python install! :) I need to learn python!